# Error installing provider "aws": openpgp: signature made by unknown entity,version 0.11.14

Tags: terraform

We started to see the below error during terraform initialization.

**Error installing provider "aws": openpgp: signature made by unknown entity.**

Current terraform version --> 0.11.14

Any thoughts on the fix without upgrading my terraform version?

Thanks,
Vamsi

Comment: It is also possible to stop checking signature if user is ok with it. `rm /tfenv/use-gpgv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashicorp have rotated the PGP key they use. Please see the following article:
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-updates-for-hcsec-2021-12/23570

For further reference, you can see in the latest CHANGELOG for v0.11:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v0.11/CHANGELOG.md#01115-april-26-2021

*Unfortunately, you will need to upgrade to version 0.11.15* (Note: There are no deprecations, unless you are using 0.11.2 or earlier.)

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to 0.11.15 worked for me to. ALso make sure that you update your executable if you are on windows. Otherwise *terraform init* tries to run a configuration with version 0.11.15 as requirement but only has an older verison to work with

Answer (score 2):

For me, I added the version on the provider and it worked.
Here is an example on AWS:

```
provider "aws" {
  allowed_account_ids = ["${var.allowed_account_id}"]
  profile             = "${var.profile}"
  region              = "${var.region}"
  version             = "~> 2.63"
}
```

Hope it can help someone without breaking their terraform modules.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

upgrading to 0.11.15 worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In this article, they are suggesting to upgrade terraform version from 0.11.14 to 0.11.15. We tried to upgrade the terraform version and it worked.

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/hashicorp/terraform/28571/830497438
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-updates-for-hcsec-2021-12/23570